# Computed Observable change does not update title attribute in UI (using knockout-bootstrap.js)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there anyway to trigger an update of the title attribute of my  element in this JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YPXYJ/9/

Note that the tooltip in the data-bind attribute of the  element is part of the knockout-bootstrap.js library

```
<label data-bind="text: copyOtherPartyHelpText()"></label>
<br />
<br />
 <i class="icon-question-sign" data-bind="tooltip: { title: copyOtherPartyHelpText(), placement: 'top', trigger: 'hover' }"></i>
<br />
<br />
<a style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click:changeHelpText">Click HERE To Change Label Text</a>

function MyViewModel() {
    this._copyOtherPartyHelpText = ko.observable();
    this.readOnlyView = ko.observable(true);


    this.copyOtherPartyHelpText = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var value = this._copyOtherPartyHelpText();

            if (value) {
                return value;
            }

            if (this.readOnlyView()) {
                value = 'Currently Disabled';
            } else {
                value = 'Match/agree to this term.';
            }
            //this makes things even worse, it is an initialization workaround
            //_copyOtherPartyHelpText(value);

            return value;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this._copyOtherPartyHelpText(value);
        },
        owner: this
    });

    this.changeHelpText = function(){
        this.copyOtherPartyHelpText('help text updated but not tooltip');
    }
}


ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: it doesn't look like you are making the viewModel properly.

Comment: This is an excerpt of my very large viewModel ;)

Comment: Well we can't tell you what you what he problem is with only half the problem. Please try to recreate the issue in a smaller sample, preferably using http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console/browser error log will tell you:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: copyOtherPartyHelpText is not defined

You'd have to reference your function calls with `this.` or the inner function will go looking for *window*.copyOtherPartyHelpText  instead.

I'd recommend using a local variable named `self` (as they often do in the knockoutjs documentation and tutorials) in your view model, so you can always reference its properties safely and easily from inside, as demonstrated in your modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YPXYJ/3/

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // More code here...

    this.changeHelpText = function(){
        alert('changeHelpText called');
        self.copyOtherPartyHelpText('help text and UI updated');
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Inside the tooltip binding for the title, you don't call the value accessor but instead reference to the observable function like so:

old:

```
<i class="icon-question-sign" data-bind="tooltip: { title: copyOtherPartyHelpText(), placement: 'top', trigger: 'hover' }"></i>
```

new:

```
<i class="icon-question-sign" data-bind="tooltip: { title: copyOtherPartyHelpText, placement: 'top', trigger: 'hover' }"></i>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/YPXYJ/11/

Comment: @Brian click my linked JSFiddle, it does work for me.
Note that I only posted an excerpt of my modifications here, the `write` function also had a reference that needed the `this` (or `self` in my example). - **EDIT** ah you deleted your comment, now I look silly ;-)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks and I gave you an up, though this isn't the answer as I didn't think I need to include that I am trying to update the title attribute in the UI but I do, so I have changed my JsFiddle

Comment: Thanks @UweB, yes I am aware of the attr binding. The tooltip binding is coming from a knockout extension library called knockout-bootstrap.js. I am using it to trigger a nice tool tip overlay from the Twitter Bootstrap library. It is difficult to call the tooltip initialization when using Knockout, normally you do this in the document.ready If you look at my external resources you will see the knockout-bootstrap.js

Comment: Yay, I think I finally fixed it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You needed the "this." when reffering to 'this._copyOtherPartyHelpText()' and '**this**.copyOtherPartyHelpText()'

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/FtMdZ/2/

```
ko.observable();
    this.readOnlyView = ko.observable(true);


    this.copyOtherPartyHelpText = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var value = this._copyOtherPartyHelpText();

            if (value) {
                return value;
            }

            if (this.readOnlyView()) {
                value = 'Currently Disabled';
            } else {
                value = 'Match/agree to this term.';
            }
            //this makes things even worse, it is an initialization workaround
            //_copyOtherPartyHelpText(value);

            return value;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this._copyOtherPartyHelpText(value);
        },
        owner: this
    });

    this.changeHelpText = function(){
        alert('changeHelpText called');
        this.copyOtherPartyHelpText('help text and UI updated');
    }
}


ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: I gave you an up, though this isn't the answer, I didn't think I need to include that I am trying to update the title attribute in the UI but I do, so I have changed my JsFiddle

Comment: @Brian - Can you clarify what you mean beacause I didn't see a 'title' attribute in any of your tags in the jsFiddle. Is this closer you what you're trying to do: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: So for my issue I am using a library called knockout-bootstrap.js. This adds the knockout binding so that <i databind="tooltip: { title: copyOtherPartyHelpText(), options}"></i> works. You will see if you hover over the little question mark icon in the JSFiddle end result that it shows the original value of my Computed Observable but not my updated value after the click event, thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for you help @Xion Dark, wish I could give you a couple ups